# INPUT, INPUT_KEYBOARD, ip were not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{

    // This structure will be used to create the keyboard
    // input event.
    INPUT ip;

    // Pause for 10 seconds.
    Sleep(1000*10);

    // Set up a generic keyboard event.
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    // Press the "F5" key
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x74; // virtual-key code for the "F5" key
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    // Release the "F5" key
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    // Exit normally
    return 0;
}
```

The codes above are simulating to press `F5` button, but there are some errors related to declaration.
`INPUT, INPUT_KEYBOARD, ip` were not declared in this scope.
How to solve it?

Comment: I use eclipse to compile on window XP. Actually, which libraries are needed and included in codes?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what compiler and platform toolset you're using it's hard to determine what, exactly, is wrong. [Reading the fine manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> **Header** Winuser.h (include Windows.h)

Which you're doing.

It also says:

> A problem with INPUT using
>
> When I try to use the INPUT structure, my compiler tells me this structure is undeclared, but I have included `<windows.h>`. After some searching, I find a solution, the `<winable.h>` should also be included. I don't know why, but it works.
>
> MarrySunny
> 12/6/2011

Although you'd probably be better off using a recent version of Microsoft Visual Studio and the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use "SendInput()", which isn't available in *some* versions of Windows.

One possibility is to this:

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
...
```

This might force Windows to use a *specific* version ... and might (depending on your specific platform) work exactly like you want :)

Here is the documentation:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Another possibility might be to substitute an OLDER APi, like keybd_event:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504289.aspx

To be sure, it would be useful to know your specfic:

- Platform: Windows 7?
- Compiler: MSVS 2013?
- Library: Microsoft-provided Win32 library?  "Something else"?

Comment: I use eclipse to compile on window XP